# HIbernate 5 same entity multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an entity called OHLC that encapsulates the list of columns. And I have multiple tables that stores the tick of financial data at 1min/5mins/15mins interval. Basically each table (namely, ohlc1min, ohlc5min/ohlc15min) has the same tuple of data with same column names. I didn't use persistance.xml for mapping. How can I map to different table when using session.save/session.merge with the commonly used entity OHLC?

Entity Structure

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ohlc1min")
public class OHLC implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 779384126251139719L;
    private Long id;
    private String stock;
    private Date tickDate;
    private String source;

    private String date;
    private double open;
    private double high;
    private double low;
    private double close;
    private long volume;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "stock", nullable = false)
    public String getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(String stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
...
```

Controller:

```
        try {
          //transaction.begin();

            for(OHLC ohlc : allOHLC) {

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd  HH:mm:ss");
                ohlc.setTickDate(sdf.parse(ohlc.getDate()));
                //temp = OHLCController.createOHLC(ohlc);
                try {
                    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                    session.merge(ohlc);
                    transaction.commit();
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    transaction.rollback();
                }
            }
            HibernateUtil.shutdown();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Create a base class with all the fields, extend it into whatever different ones for each table